# sorting through an array to place code in the proper divs through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Currently making a website to index and play movies stored on my hard drive that I've recently pulled off dvds just as a little side project. I have a 'master movie list' JSON file with all the data I need for each movie including the name, video source, video poster source, and genre which I would like to allow the use of placing a movie in multiple different genres.

Currently the problem I'm having is while I'm parsing through the genre list generated its not placing the html in the correct ID that id like it to on the webpage.

For example: 
"genre":"comedy,recent,scifi"

I went about it how I thought I should, through getJSON and setting an output variable to which I get the genre value, split to make it an array, and get the element by going through each of them in a loop. Its not placing it in the right place though. The example above would be placed in comedy, recent, scifi, horror, and a few others for some reason and I have absolutely no reason why.

```js
$.getJSON('/webresource/data/movies.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var output = '';
  var ele = $('');
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {

    output += '<div class="video_box lazy-background" video-src="' +
      val.video_src + '" video-poster-src="' +
      val.video_poster_src + '">' +
      '<h5>' + val.name + '</h5>' +
      '</div> ';

    var genres = val.genre;
    var genresarray = genres.split(',');

    for (i = 0; i < genresarray.length; i++) {
      var genreelement = $('#' + genresarray[i]);
      genreelement.html(output);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
[ {
  "name": "a star is born", "video_src":"/files/movies/A%20Star%20Is%20Born/astarisborn.mp4", "video_poster_src":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51R-TU6VaTL.jpg", "genre":"recently,romance,drama"
}

] // this is an example of the json
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="genre_box">
  <h3>RECENTLY ADDED</h3>
  <div class="scroll_box" id="recently"></div>
</div>

<div class="genre_box">
  <h3>ACTION</h3>
  <div class="scroll_box" id="action"></div>
</div>

<div class="genre_box">
  <h3>COMEDY</h3>
  <div class="scroll_box" id="comedy"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `output` variable is being appended to and kept on every iteration of your `$.each` loop. What you want is to append to the end of `$("#action")`, `$("#comedy")`, etc. You should do something along these lines:

```
$.getJSON('/webresource/data/movies.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {

    var output = '<div class="video_box lazy-background" video-src="' +
      val.video_src + '" video-poster-src="' +
      val.video_poster_src + '">' +
      '<h5>' + val.name + '</h5>' +
      '</div> ';

    var genres = val.genre;
    var genresarray = genres.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < genresarray.length; i++) {
      var genreelement = $('#' + genresarray[i]);
      genreelement.append(output);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I ended up with the same solution after hours of headache but yours is a little more simple which I like so! Thanks!